# Error on setting up workspace for Minecraft modding

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to set up the workspace for creating mods for Minecraft. I installed JRE, installed JDK 8. I installed eclipse. I downloaded the latest mdk file of minecraft forge. I setup the environment variables for JDK. I extracted the forge zip file. I opened powershell in the extracted forge folder. I ran the command `.\gradlew setupDecompWorkspace`. I am getting the following error:

```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'First Mod'.
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':_compileJava_1'.
>    > Could not resolve com.mojang:patchy:1.1.
>      Required by:
>          project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
>       > Skipped due to earlier error
>    > Could not resolve oshi-project:oshi-core:1.1.
>      Required by:
>          project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
>       > Skipped due to earlier error
>    > Could not resolve com.ibm.icu:icu4j-core-mojang:51.2.
>      Required by:
>          project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
>       > Skipped due to earlier error
>    > Could not resolve com.mojang:javabridge:1.0.22.
>      Required by:
>          project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
>       > Skipped due to earlier error
>    > Could not resolve com.mojang:brigadier:1.0.17.
>      Required by:
>          project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
>       > Skipped due to earlier error
>    > Could not resolve com.mojang:datafixerupper:2.0.24.
>      Required by:
>          project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
>       > Skipped due to earlier error
>    > Could not resolve com.mojang:authlib:1.5.25.
>      Required by:
>          project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
>       > Skipped due to earlier error
>    > Could not resolve com.mojang:text2speech:1.11.3.
>      Required by:
>          project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
>       > Skipped due to earlier error
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> 
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 5.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

How do I fix this error? I even tried the other command that I found online. ".\gradlew genEclipseRuns` this gives the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'First Mod'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':_compileJava_1'.
   > Could not resolve com.mojang:patchy:1.1.
     Required by:
         project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve oshi-project:oshi-core:1.1.
     Required by:
         project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.ibm.icu:icu4j-core-mojang:51.2.
     Required by:
         project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.mojang:javabridge:1.0.22.
     Required by:
         project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.mojang:brigadier:1.0.17.
     Required by:
         project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.mojang:datafixerupper:2.0.24.
     Required by:
         project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.mojang:authlib:1.5.25.
     Required by:
         project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.mojang:text2speech:1.11.3.
     Required by:
         project : > net.minecraft:client:1.15.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 44s
```

This is the gradle.build file present in the minecraft forge folder:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '3.+', changing: true
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
// Only edit below this line, the above code adds and enables the necessary things for Forge to be setup.
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version = '1.0'
group = 'com.yourname.modid' // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = 'modid'

sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = compileJava.sourceCompatibility = compileJava.targetCompatibility = '1.8' // Need this here so eclipse task generates correctly.

minecraft {
    // The mappings can be changed at any time, and must be in the following format.
    // snapshot_YYYYMMDD   Snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable_#            Stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. they may not always work.
    // Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '20190719-1.14.3'
    // makeObfSourceJar = false // an Srg named sources jar is made by default. uncomment this to disable.

    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    // Default run configurations.
    // These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            args '--mod', 'examplemod', '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/')

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Specify the version of Minecraft to use, If this is any group other then 'net.minecraft' it is assumed
    // that the dep is a ForgeGradle 'patcher' dependency. And it's patches will be applied.
    // The userdev artifact is a special name and will get all sorts of transformations applied to it.
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.15.1-30.0.26'

    // You may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs or you may define them like so..
    // compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    // compile "some.group:artifact:version"

    // Real examples
    // compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    // compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // The 'provided' configuration is for optional dependencies that exist at compile-time but might not at runtime.
    // provided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // These dependencies get remapped to your current MCP mappings
    // deobf 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // For more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading by the runtime..
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
            "Specification-Title": "examplemod",
            "Specification-Vendor": "examplemodsareus",
            "Specification-Version": "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
            "Implementation-Title": project.name,
            "Implementation-Version": "${version}",
            "Implementation-Vendor" :"examplemodsareus",
            "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}

// Example configuration to allow publishing using the maven-publish task
// we define a custom artifact that is sourced from the reobfJar output task
// and then declare that to be published
// Note you'll need to add a repository here
def reobfFile = file("$buildDir/reobfJar/output.jar")
def reobfArtifact = artifacts.add('default', reobfFile) {
    type 'jar'
    builtBy 'reobfJar'
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact reobfArtifact
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file:///${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to remove the cache with rm `-rf ~/.gradle`. For me it looks like you are missing some dependencies. Try to google something like gradle could note resolve dependencies and i think you will find a solution.

Comment: @Z3RP doesn't help. I am still getting the same error. I even tried different version of minecraft forge. still same error

Comment: Can you show us your gradle configuration ?

Comment: @Z3RP how do I show the configuration? I have not downloaded the gradle separately. I am using the same that comes with minecraft forge

Comment: there must be  a gradle.build file. That is the config file

Comment: @Z3RP I added the contents of build.gradle file to the question.

Comment: Can you try this configuration or just to change the repo url
[gradle.build](https://gist.github.com/Runemoro/f8ea27bece4806d8169c47ff8dcdf69a)

Comment: @Z3RP I replaced the repositories and dependencies part as per the repo. but now I get error the implementation() for the first implementation in the dependencies could not be found

Comment: You might get better help on the [forge forums](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/forum/70-modder-support/).

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE I have already posted it there. I thought posting at both sites, so it will be resolved relatively faster

Comment: I had made a cursory check and didn't see a thread that matched (no similar user name and only seemingly related thread had a different error).

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/79450-build-failed-with-exception-error-of-setting-up-workspace/?tab=comments#comment-379458 this one

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE also,now other things are working but I am  getting error that `client-extra.jar` could not be found. and it showed a folder where it searched and it doesn't have that file

Comment: It should be generated by the setup/decomp process.

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE should the `.\gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` command be used first or just `.\gradlew eclipse` is enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think the gradle version you are using is too high.Youre currently using gradle 5.0 and you should try to use gradle 4.9.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing every instance of "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven" with "https://libraries.minecraft.net" in build.gradle fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me is simple instead of `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace`, use `gradlew eclipse`. For those of you who found this as a result on google, it won't with Intellij.